# XMPP + OTR Encryption in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, xmpp

Are there any existing libraries that would allow me to develop a chat program in PHP using XMPP and OTR encryption?

I'm looking to create a web chat software using XMPP and OTR that would allow for encrypted 1-on-1 communication over the web.

PHP is desired but not required, both XMPP and OTR are vitally necesarry. Must be web based and must not leave or be able to access anything on a user's computer (read: NO JAVA.)

Any help that anybody could give me on this subject would be appreciated.

Comment: Use SSL: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0035.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Python &

> http://python-otr-old.pentabarf.de/

or C, extends to C# with libotr

> https://otr.cypherpunks.ca/software.php